# How to do your own Wolfram Function-of-the-Day style GIF?

Tags: export, image

Anyone know how Wolfram tweets out GIFs of a notebook running some code like this one?
[image]
https://twitter.com/WolframResearch/status/1083739334879182848

It's a lovely way to show how to build/iterate functions as distinct from showing the end result.

Comment: Presumably some standard screen tracking/recording tool (I use [peek on Ubuntu](https://github.com/phw/peek) personally). I haven't had much luck using the built in screen capture stuff

Comment: The actual writing could easily be automated by scraping from the docs and using some nice FE programming. The actual recording process is almost certainly from a recording too.

Comment: I'm sure they just use a screen recording software. Mac has one built-in, and OBS is a good one on Windows.

Comment: thought so - was wondering if there was some set of functions I hadn't heard of